# can i detect arrow key as signal in linux?

Tags: c++, linux, signals

I am creating a game in c++. I want to know if I can make my program to detect arrow keys as signals like SIGINT for ctrl+c. Also, I don't want to use ncurses, as it has its separate buffer and doesn't work well with iostream.

Comment: The short answer is; no, you can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but you can use `select()` on stdin, as described here: [select() on STDIN and Incoming Socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39402886/select-on-stdin-and-incoming-socket)

Comment: I would recommend [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) instead of the old `select`